# How to get photo file name in a zip archive

Tags: r

I have several photos in a zip archive, such as 1000.jpg, 1012.jpg, 3056.jpg

How can I extract these photo's names and create a list called custID?

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
custID <- unzip("test.zip", files = NULL, list = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE,
                junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal",
                setTimes = FALSE)[1]
```